# Post request wrapped with optional text

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

I have a POST request using AlamoFire. But when reading the payload in Java I am seeing one param with Optinal(""). Code is below

```
        if let deviceState = OneSignal.getDeviceState() {
        
        let headers = [
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
        let onesignalid = deviceState.userId
   
        let parameters1: [String: Any] = [
            "displayName" : name,
            "uid" : id,
            "email" : email,
             "onesignal" : onesignalid!

        ]
        
       
        Alamofire.request(Constan.URL+"/AddUser", method: .post, parameters: parameters1,encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
```

JAVA reading payload

```
displayName: Hdherbe email: azaz@gmail.com onesignal : Optional("12345-8296-11ec-9b5c-46d63a54459b")
```

Comment: How did you get `userId`? Could it be that's it's real value is `Optional("12345-8296-11ec-9b5c-46d63a54459b")`, to it's not correctly save at previously, or maybe it's double optional?

Comment: Its not. When I do with Postman it works fine without Optional("")

Comment: How did you set `deviceState.userId`? I hope it's not with string interpolation like `userId = "\(myValue)"`. I think that either iit's double optional, or it really has "Optional("...")" as value. Could you print `deviceState.userId?.count`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply define parameters and values like the below code:

```
var parameters: [String: Any] = [
    "displayName": name,
    "uid": id,
    "email": email,
]

if let originalID = originalID { parameters["onesignal"] = originalID }
```

Comment: var parameters: [String: Any] = = [:] ?

Comment: Getting error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'" on third line

Comment: @user1163234 I edited my answer just now. Check it, please.

Comment: didnt work same result...

Comment: @user1163234 Another way is "onesignal" : onesignalid ?? "", try it may be helping